# accountmanager refresh token(offline access)

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I use google login through account manager in my android app. I can get accesstoken which I send to server and server can create/login new user. Accesstoken is valid only 3600seconds. Problem is that server can not update user's info after this time expires. Web app requires check user's info periodically.

How can I get authentication token and refresh token from android account manager so than server can use refresh token to update data periodically? I don't want use login through webview in android app.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now possible: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app

You request a one-time authorisation code, send it to your server and your server exchanges it for an access token and refresh token.

Comment: Hi ade, I follow the instructions but I didn't understand where I can find the "one-time authorisation code" that I have to send to my server to get the refresh token. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you can't, which I'm sure is not the answer you're hoping for, sorry about that! If you have a web sign in, you can use the hybrid flow to get a refresh token on the server as well (see https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow), but there's no way of retrieving a code as part of the Android or iOS flows.

If this is something that you need for you use case, could you file a feature request on here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues - we are actively looking at the number of stars on that to gauge demand for various features.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Authorization process through account manager:**

Email id can be got from

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
String emailID = accounts[0].name; // you can retrieve using google account chooser way also
```

These lines should be run in separate token(not in UI thread).

```
String scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://gdata.youtube.com";
String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, emailID, scope);
```

save the the accessToken and use for your api access.

After one hour (i.e. 3600 seconds), we need to refresh the access token. But now google is not supporting access after one hour. We have to restart the application and use the following lines to get access token.

```
String scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://gdata.youtube.com";
String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, emailID, scope);
```

This background thread will always run in background in while loop

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't use Thread.sleep() on a background thread on Android. Thread is an expensive resource.

Schedule your code on a Handler or background service triggered by AlarmManager.