# How to get OAuth 2 refresh token using access token

Tags: android, gmail, oauth-2.0

I am developing an app in which i am using OAuth 2.0 to upload data in user Google label. I am able to connect to the users mail and after some time access token expires. 
How to get new access token using Token refresher?

I am using javamail sample code to authenticate and get access token. I am searching it from many days but did not found any running code. I am new to android, so please provide some code or complete sample code.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641734/accountmanager-refresh-tokenoffline-access

Comment: Please provide some sample code i go through your provided link but unable to get desired result. thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you halp me, i have issue likewise your one. But i work with google LogIn button and use this way https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in , but there are any words about how to get refresh token... Maybe you know how this concept have to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer now i want to share to all of you because many questions are unanswered.

to get a new token first you have to invalidate the token using below code

```
accountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", token);
```

after invalidating the token you require to get a new Token, below code provides a new Token

```
String newToken = AccountManager.get(this).getAuthToken(new Account(account, "com.google"),
                 AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, null, null).getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

now you can use your new token to authenticate and login.

Comment: i use the same code(java mail). but i send the mail in background(service) when my application is running/in taskbar it will be fine. but when i will remove from task bar that time i can't get activity object and we need activity object for  AccountManager.get(this).getAuthToken(new Account(account, "com.google"),
                 AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, null, null).getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);