# JavaMail - Refresh Token

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm working on a Java app that uses JavaMail. Currently, I'm trying to connect to a mail provider that uses OAuth2. The provider returns an access token and a refresh token. After sometime, my app doesn't work because the access token has expired. I now need to use my refresh token to get a new access token. However, I'm not sure how to do that in JavaMail.

Is there a way to use the refresh token to get a new access token in JavaMail? If so, how?

Thank you

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572088/how-to-get-oauth-2-refresh-token-using-access-token) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use JavaMail to do this, since OAuth can be used with other protocols and services.  Depending on the OAuth provider, you should be able to issue an HTTP request of the proper form to get a new access token based on the refresh token.

There's some pointers on the [JavaMail wiki](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) that might help.