# AWS Cognito: dealing with token expiration time

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-signin, amazon-cognito

I am experimenting with Cognito and when I thought it was starting to be OK, I am facing the issue of (Google) token expiring after 1 hour.

When I start with a clean device, I can sign up, use the app for 1 hour, then as soon as I need to refresh a dataset, I get and error saying the the token is not authorised.

Are there any example on how to deal with this?

Is it really something the app developers should be doing?
I was expecting the SDK to manage such things in the background.

Is it meaning that we have to check the credentialsProvider.getSessionCredentitalsExpiration() before each dataset synchronisation ?

Many thanks,
JM

**Edit 1 : Added code**

I do have a SigninActivity, but it is only called when no credentials exists at all, in theory only once the first time the user logs in.

It is built as follows (removed useless bits).
So what happens is that I authenticate right the first time, but as I never enter this activity again, maybe something is missing.

But there must be a way to refresh this token silently?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.signin);

    // Aws Credential provider
    credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), // Context
            getString(R.string.aws_identity_pool), // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
    );

    // Google connect
    findViewById(R.id.signin_with_google_btn).setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_server_client_id))
            .requestId()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this )
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin_with_google_btn);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    this.signinWithGoogle();
}

/**
 * Triggers Google signin
 */
private void signinWithGoogle() {
    Log.v(this, "Signing in with Google...");

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    this.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        this.handleGoogleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // Other stuff
    }
}


/**
 * Handle Google sign in result
 */
private void handleGoogleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

    if (result.isSuccess()) {

        Log.v(this, "Successfully logged in with Google...");

        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Log.v(this, "Signed in as %s / %s (token %s)", acct.getDisplayName(), acct.getEmail(), acct.getIdToken());
        Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
        logins.put("accounts.google.com", acct.getIdToken());
        Log.v(SigninActivity.this, "Google token <<<\n%s\n>>>", logins.get("accounts.google.com"));
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
    } else {
        // Signed out
        Log.w(this, "Failed to authenticate against Google #%d - %s", result.getStatus().getStatusCode(), result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());

        SimpleMessageDialog.show(SigninActivity.this,
                R.drawable.icon,
                R.string.error,
                R.string.sorry_error_signing_you_in_please_try_again,
                R.string.try_again);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you following all the steps documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/)? The SDK will get you AWS credentials in exchange of a valid token automatically, but if your Google token is expired, then you need to refresh it.

Comment: Hi Rachit, thanks for your answer, I have edited my question and added my code.

Generally speaking an examples on how to handle token refresh and gerenally "post sign on errors" (user did withdraw auth, this kind of things) would really really help.

Comment: So refreshing the google token is upto personal preference and we have seen developers do something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572088/how-to-get-oauth-2-refresh-token-using-access-token. 

That being said, we have heard customer requests about providing helper methods to refresh tokens and we will consider adding those in future releases.

Comment: Rachit, I can only second this requirement.
I am not having a go at you, but this is pretty disappointing that this is not managed out of the box.

Unless I am confused, this is sounding like a pretty basic requirement and the SDK should deal with kind of things in order to allow us to focus on our added value.

Comment: We have heard this request from other customers also and will consider adding this feature in future updates to the service. As always feel free to post in our forums or here if you have any questions.

Comment: What puzzles me is that I was able to reproduce a situation where Cognito deals with this on its own (see here https://github.com/ironbird-software/aws-cognito-sync-issues). So I cannot understand why the onus is on the developper when it would be much simpler for us all if the SDK was dealing with it consistently.